# How to pass long-pooling requests or web socket requests to heroku worker dyno?

Tags: python, heroku, tornado

I have a `web dyno` that handles all my web requests. If a request comes in that is a `long-pooling` request how to you pass that connection off to a `worker dyno`?

Ex. Request to `example.com/long-pooling` handled by `web dyno` needs to be passed to `worker dyno` to free up the `web dyno` for more requests.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't exactly pass on *the request*. It sounds like you want a queueing library like RQ or Celery. Essentially you queue up the long running request and then on the client side you poll for updates

- https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-rq
- https://github.com/celery/celery/